# Swift connection to database without php output

Tags: php, ios, database, swift

I have a simple question about the database structure and connection to my iOS App.

Is there any solution to get datas from my databse using Swift without PHP output? I want a PHP script which connects to the database and echo the result. The app should load the datas directly from the database like PHP (mysqli).

It is really important for me to protect the datas in the database! Nobody should see the datas when he opens a URL in the browser of my server.

Comment: No you cannot have a direct connection from the app without the database credentials being embedded within it. Sooner or later someone will unpack/decompile the app, find the creds and bam your whole database is toast. So you need some form of server side gateway code. What language you chose for that is up to you

Comment: Thanks for the clear comment! My goal is that nobody can see the data output. If anybody open the page with the data base output he can see all... Thats my problem. Is it a solution to protect the page via htaccess and open it only in the app?

Comment: Yes, the solution is the same as for a webpage - you put any sensitive data behind an authorization check. The majority of web frameworks will have this type of thing built in - what framework are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Now it is clear for me :-)
I don't use any frameworks on the webserver. A simple htaccess file is sufficient for my plan. Thanks!

Comment: Glad i could help you - yes http basic auth via htaccess would work just fine